# Header image doesn't show up on page

Tags: customization

A developer abandoned a site and I'm trying to correct it.

The header image on [this page](http://www.feoga.com/about-us/) will not show up.

This is the code in the header:

```
<?php
$image_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'header_image', true );
$image= get_attached_file( $image_id, $unfiltered );
$image_path= explode('wp-content', $image);
$main_image= 'wp-content'.$image_path[1];
if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'header_image', true ) ) : ?>
<style> .site-header { background: url("<?php echo $main_image ?>") no-repeat!important;} </style>
```

This section is outputting a style with a `.site-header` background image with a relative url; and is overwriting whatever it outputed before with the conditional `is_page()` codes.

Therefore, I am trying to use the custom field name "header_image with the value using the the correct url. it's not working. Every time I update, the url disappears in the value section and the original appears.

Please advise.

Comment: Lines 95, 115 and 121 are all trying to load a background image for the header tag.  Line 121 is overriding the others and it is returning a 404- http://www.feoga.com/about-us/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/AboutUsHeader1.png

Comment: The line numbers are no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thing to check, it happened to me as well, but I was accidently deleting some of the testing data and accidently wiped the post data for headers along with them.

So make sure that you are not deleting your data for headers somewhere - just a suggestion.